# Netlogo: most efficient way to code with gis:apply-coverage?

Tags: gis, netlogo

I'm copying variables from a SHP file to patches with the gis:apply-coverage command. The issue is that they are 147 different variables, so I want to write code as efficient as possible. The variables are:

```
patches-own [ 
SUBSECTOR HARE HAUN HAMU TUSAPAB TUPLPBSC TUECOTEA TUAVSCVB TURUEATF 
INMIAA INMIEM INIBRBR INIBRBA INIRMT INIRP INIRPM INIRYD INIRP1 INIARIR 
INAAGCU INAGAEG INAGACE INAGAES INAGAFO INAGAAA INAGAAP INAAFSI INAAFVH 
INAPCPE INAPCCC ESCSVMS ESCSVTE ESCSBTE ESCSBAP ESCSBAL ESCSBTI ESCSBLV 
ESCSBEL ESCSBCA ESCSBRM ESCSBAI ESCSDTE ESCSDCC ESCSDTA ESCSDMP ESCSDSF 
ESCSDDA ESCSDHM ESCSDTP ESCSDCA ESCSDAC ESCSDCV ESCSDSS ESCSDCS ESCSCRE 
ESCSCMA ESECVJN ESECVPR ESECVSG ESECBEA ESECBAI ESECBBG ESECBTE ESECDET 
ESECDGA ESECCLG ESECCPO ESECCPH ESECCAJ ESECCTC ESECVUU ESSSBCS ESSSBHO 
ESSSBHE ESSSDCC ESSSDOR ESSSDCI ESSSCCA ESSSRHR ESDRVPC ESDRVJV ESDRVJI 
ESDRVCD ESDRBPV ESDRBSF ESDRBUC ESDRBCC ESDRBSD ESDRBED ESDRDCG ESDRDAF 
ESDRDED ESDRDBP ESDRDCI ESDRDCN ESDRDCE ESDRCZO ESDRCCC ESDRCCI ESAPBMP 
ESAPBOG ESAPBJC ESAPDDM ESAPCPM ESAPCRP ESAPCAD ESAPCEM ESSUVCP ESSUBCS 
ESSUB1 ESSUBCE  ESSUCIE ESSUCEP ESCTVAS ESCTVOT ESCTBAC ESCTBAT ESCTBCT 
ESCTBET ESCTB1  ESCTBES ESCTBAP ESCTDOT ESCTDTT ESCTDHH ESCTD1  ESCTCTT 
ESCTC1  ESCTRTV ESCTRTA ESCTRTF ESCTRTI ESCTRPU ESCTRTE ESCTRMA ESCTRIP 
UEGCC   UECAH   UEPES   UETMA   UEMON UEAER UEPTAN UEPD UECB UERSPT UEPRE
]
```

and the code I wrote is:

```
to copy-values-to-patch
  gis:apply-coverage Subsectores_090121-dataset "SUBSECTOR" Subsector
  gis:apply-coverage Subsectores_090121-dataset "HARE" HARE
  gis:apply-coverage Subsectores_090121-dataset "HAUN" HAUN
  gis:apply-coverage Subsectores_090121-dataset "HAMU" HAMU
  ....
  gis:apply-coverage Subsectores_090121-dataset "UEPRE" UEPRE
end
```

In this format, there are 149 lines of code, but I think there must be a way to write it in a more practical way (for example, not needing to write the gis:apply-coverage command 147 times). As anyone can see, I'm still new at coding, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Regards,

Javier